# Algorithm to solve optimal clustering of word vectors

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, k-means

I have word vectors split out into N groups, where each group contains M vectors. The problem is to find an optimal clustering of vectors where one and only one vector appears from each of the N groups.

As an example, say we had 3 groups of vectors as so:

1. {"Hot Dog", "Hot sauce", "Hotshot"}
2. {"Hamburger", "Hamburg", "Hamburgler"}
3. {"Pizza", "Pisa", "Piazza"}

The optimal cluster would be {"Hot Dog", "Hamburger", "Pizza"} because according to some function I have F(), these vectors are clustered closely to each other within the vector space I have defined.

I can arrive at this result in a brute force way by merely trying every combination. But as N and M grow, this becomes unfeasible. Is there a dynamic programming approach I could use? Any reference algorithm I can look up?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

To clarify my example above, each of those strings is like an ID for a vector so to rephrase it, Group 1 is {v1, v2, v3} Group 2 is {v4, v5, v6}, Group 3 is {v7, v8, v9}.

My desired output is {v1, v4, v7} but in a non-brute force way.

@m69's comment below correctly describes what I mean by a cluster - a group of vectors whose distance to one another as computed by some function **F()** is all within some **threshold t**.

Comment: What do you mean by `these vectors are clustered closely to each other`?

Comment: @Hearen Obviously there's a function F(a,b) that returns a distance between two elements, and the distances between "Hot Dog", "Hamburger" and "Pizza" are small compared to the distances with other elements.

Comment: "As an example, say we had 3 groups of vectors" and you showed three vectors actually instead groups of vectors. When someone says "groups" they mean similar objects grouped into one. Here it seems its just a vector of strings and each vector is a group of strings. Maybe thats what you had in your mind. If so please correct the question so others will find it easy to understand.

Comment: what would the score of the 3 words be? The sum of distances of all pairs? F(Hot Dog, Hamburger) + F(Hot Dog, Pizza) + F(Hamburger, Pizza) ?